# Automatically show custom keyboard for EditText. Android

Tags: android, keyboard

I want to make the custom keyboard in my android application and show it for specific EditText.
I've read documentation and found, that I need to extend the InputMethodService class. But I didn't find out how to show this keyboard automatically for some EditText.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution I wanted here: http://www.infiniterecursion.us/2011/02/android-activity-custom-keyboard.html

Comment: Thanks, that was the tiny piece I was missing. Already had my custom keyboard and was just looking for a way to actually show it, without having to set it as the default keyboard for the whole app/phone (for which it is not suited/intended anyway).

Comment: Good tutorials for custom keyboard are [this](http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm) and [this](http://androidpadanam.wordpress.com/2013/05/29/customkeyboard-example/). The first contains good explanation, but in the second you can find how to fix the problems with the cursor.

Answer (score 5):

There is a example present in `Android SDK`

Load that Android Project

> New --> Android Sample Project --> Soft Keyboard

To show your keyboard for particular edit text box you need to override `OnTouchlistener`